# Show that $3$ divides $p-2$ if and only if $3$ divides $p+1$, where $p$ ia a prime different from $3$..

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

I can observe this but unable to prove this result.
If we start by taking the values of $p$ when $3|p+1$ and $p\neq 3$.
We get the values of such $p$'s: $5, 11, 17, 23, 41, 47, 53, 59, 71, 83, 89, \cdots $

In each case $3$ divides $p-2$. It also holds in the converse sense.

Please help me to prove this. Thank you.

Comment: It need not even hold for primes, but integers in general really. $p+1$ and $p-2$ differ by $3$, so it's clear to see this is true whenever $p$ is an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $p+1-(p-2)=3\iff p+1=3+p-2$  or $p-2=p+1-3$

So, if $3|(p-2)\iff 3|(p+1)$

Answer (score 1):

The result follows from
$$p-2 \equiv 0\bmod 3 \Leftrightarrow p+1\equiv 0\bmod 3  $$